# C# and SQL recursive searching of a table

Tags: c#, sql, lambda

I have a db table that consists simply of a column of current ids (the key) and a second columnm with their previous ids. The ids are for a specific object, but they have to change periodically. I wish to follow the trail of changing ids and output the entire id lineage of an object. I have done this in c# after converting the table to text and using lists. But, is there an SQL query usable in c# that can recurse the table for the full lineage instead?

Table: RelatedIDs

CurrID,PrevID (table)

2,1

4,3

101,2

would produce the lineages:

1 -> 2 -> 101

3 -> 4

Thank you.

Comment: Look up Common Table Expressions if you are on SqlServer.

Comment: Perhaps I'm completely misunderstanding the question here because other's answers/comments make no sense to me. Do you want *one row* for each bottom level object with the entire lineage? What kind of output are you expecting from SQL?

Comment: Yes, I am after a one row answer for each. I need to check id numbers that can occur anywhere in the sequence, and find out what they are at now.I did not specify this, but a prevID can occasionally branch out into multiple CurrIDs. To help the others, this relates to land, so what was once a single parcel, could become two parcels later on. Or 2 could be come one. So each possible branch is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in MS SQL 2005 or greater with a common table expression (See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
; -- You'll only need this if it's not the first statement in the batch
WITH Recursive AS (
  SELECT CurrID AS ID, CAST(CurrID AS nvarchar) AS Path
  FROM SourceTable
  WHERE PrevID IS NULL -- You need to anchor your first result

  UNION ALL

  SELECT S.CurrID, P.Path + ' > ' + CAST(CurrID AS nvarchar)
  FROM SourceTable S 
  INNER JOIN Recursive R ON R.CurrID = S.PrevID
)
SELECT * FROM Recursive
```

You can then filter the final query to get what you need. To filter out only the full unique paths from top top bottom requires a bit of creativity, but it can be done - with something like this (I haven't been able to test this, so it might need a bit of refinement):

```
; -- You'll only need this if it's not the first statement in the batch
WITH Recursive AS (
  SELECT CurrID AS ID, CAST(CurrID AS nvarchar) AS Path, 0 AS Depth
  FROM SourceTable
  WHERE PrevID IS NULL -- You need to anchor your first result

  UNION ALL

  SELECT S.CurrID, P.Path + ' > ' + CAST(CurrID AS nvarchar), P.Depth + 1
  FROM SourceTable S 
  INNER JOIN Recursive R ON R.CurrID = S.PrevID
)
SELECT Path 
FROM Recursive A
LEFT JOIN Recursive B ON B.Path LIKE A.Path + '%' AND A.Depth < B.Depth
WHERE B.Path IS NULL
```

You should be aware that on large data sets, string processing like this isn't going to be fast, so you have to be wary of it when deciding to do things this way.

SQL 2008 has a data type called `hierarchyid` which could also be useful. I have never used it so I can't really help, but if you're interested, this should get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx

Comment: this is still going to produce one result set row per parent/child pair, which he already has...

Comment: That's what a WHERE clause is for ;)

Comment: Apologies. I have been out of office for a week. Thank you Bennor. I will try this out and post the results. Since I am dealing with a DB I want to try a DB answer.